# Firebase configure makes iOS crash

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have implemented Firebase analytics (and messaging) in my Unity game (iOS & Android).
It is working on both platforms, but on a few iOS devices I was getting the error that FIRApp configure was not called. In the documentation it is stated that I need to add `[FIRApp configure];` to the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function (which I forgot).

After I did this my app crashes with a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception. When I comment the configure my app works again.
I am also seeing this error when it crashes:

> CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9806)

Some said that putting the configure into the Init function would fix it, but for me it gives the same error.

Comment: Which version of Firebase are you linking?  What does your POD file say?  Have you followed this guide line by line?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Comment: I am using version 3.0.3. What is the POD file? I did everything according to the guide.

Comment: Sorry, I'm checking versions now...